# Laravel5 assign Middleware to route patterns

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Assume i have 1 application and two external packages.

- Package 1 defines routes like `api/v1/package1/foo`
- Package 2 defines routes like `api/v1/package2/bar`

In my main application i want to apply some `Middleware` for each `api/v1/*` route.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you not create a global middleware class that checks the URI of incoming requests, and acts accordingly?

Comment: This is the best suggestion i got so far, after a day of reading. Im testing bits and it seems to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Use [Route Groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups) to accomplish this. You can set prefix or domain groups, namespace groups, and middleware groups this way.

For example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'package1', 'middleware' => 'package1.middleware']), function({
        Route::get('foo', 'FooController@foo');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'package2', 'middleware' => 'package2.middleware']), function({
        Route::get('bar', 'BarController@bar');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope buddy, routes are already declared in package1 and package2, i've no control on them

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you have incoming requests from package 1 and package 2, which are sites that you have no control over, and you are looking to apply filters to the requests you receive from them?  If so, you need to apply the filters to the routes in your application that are being requested. So, you should create a custom middleware (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) that checks for the Referrer, and acts accordingly. You can apply it globally, or only to specific routes in App\Http\Kernel